# -[NSResponder _tryRetain] crash

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory-management, appkit, macos-catalina

**I got crashes from users.** This one:

```
Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [79055]

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff30cc820a -[NSResponder _tryRetain] + 92
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff693a1e1d objc_loadWeakRetained + 351
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff693a3adc objc_loadWeak + 15
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3075605a -[NSTableRowData ensureGroupRowIndexes] + 256
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff306e8161 -[NSTableView _isGroupRow:] + 106
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff30807219 -[NSTableView _sendDelegateHeightOfRow:] + 144
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff307f01cb -[NSTableView _safeSendDelegateHeightOfRow:] + 79
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff307f00f7 -[NSTableView _uncachedRectHeightOfRow:] + 274
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff307efe8c -[_NSTableRowHeightStorage _cacheRowHeights] + 52
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3068a77d -[_NSTableRowHeightStorage _ensureRowHeights] + 57
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3068a6cf -[_NSTableRowHeightStorage computeTableHeightForNumberOfRows:] + 80
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff30689b93 -[NSTableView _minimumFrameSize] + 73
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3068918c -[NSTableView tile] + 285
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff306b014e -[NSTableView bounds] + 100
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3065d920 -[NSView(NSInternal) _setLayerNeedsDisplayInViewRect:] + 171
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff306136b5 -[NSView setNeedsDisplayInRect:] + 767
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff30682a18 -[NSTableView _tileAndRedisplayAll] + 217
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3342c35f __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff334bcc73 ___CFXRegistrationPost1_block_invoke + 63
19  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff334bc308 _CFXRegistrationPost1 + 372
20  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff334349be ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 97
21  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3339cce2 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1575
22  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3339c172 _CFXNotificationPost + 1351
23  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff35a6336b -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 59
My App Code
```

And this one(from another user):

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [68319]

Application Specific Information:
Refcount overflow in NSResponder or subclass. Too many unbalanced -retains!

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3a50820a -[NSResponder _tryRetain] + 92
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff72d7ae1d objc_loadWeakRetained + 351
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff72d7cadc objc_loadWeak + 15
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff39fa1f0b -[NSTableRowData rowViewAtRow:createIfNeeded:] + 47
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff3a05577b -[NSTableView viewAtColumn:row:makeIfNecessary:] + 29
    My App Code
```

**The following message scared me at first glance.**

> Application Specific Information: Refcount overflow in NSResponder or
>   subclass. Too many unbalanced -retains!

**Finally, I did manage to reproduce the crash into the test project:**

```
@implementation AppDelegate

NSString * const SIFTFilePresentationViewIdentifier = @"sift:file presentation";

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [self registerCells];// < - - - Commenting only this line fixes the issue.

    self.outlineView.delegate = self;
    self.outlineView.dataSource = self;
}

- (void)registerCells {
    NSNib *nib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"SIFTFileView" bundle:nil];
    [self.outlineView registerNib:nib forIdentifier:SIFTFilePresentationViewIdentifier];
}

- (NSInteger)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView numberOfChildrenOfItem:(id)item {
    if (item == nil) {
        //Works fine:
        //10.14.5 (18F132)
        //MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017)

        //Crashes:
        //10.15.1 (19B88)
        //MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018)

        //2^25 = 33554432
        return 33560000;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item {
    if (item == nil) {
        return @"321";
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item {
    return item == nil;
}

- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isGroupItem:(id)item {// < - - - Commenting only this method fixes the issue.
    return item == nil;
}

@end
```

**Project reproduces the issue:** https://github.com/Vladimir-Nn/NSTableViewRefcountOverflow

**Some related discussions on the web:**

> NSParagraphStyle had a 19-bit inline retain count with no overflow
>   protection (i.e. it incorrectly deallocated if you retained it too
>   much and then called some releases). This occasionally crashed in
>   Xcode (rdar://16008112).

https://forums.swift.org/t/shrinking-the-heap-object-header/1078

> I can't really see any memory management going on in the LWJGL code
>   that would cause the overflow. Therefore the crash appears to be
>   originating from inside the firstResponder method. If it doesn't
>   happen in previous versions of MacOS, I'm guessing its probably an OS
>   bug or some sort of change in behaviour in how that method worked.

http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=6951.msg36545#msg36545

> I don't immediately understand why this would be crashing, we're just
>   asking an NSTextView to scroll itself.
>
> I did notice in the crash report that there's an info text of Refcount
>   overflow in NSResponder or subclass. Too many unbalanced -retains! -
>   @asmagill do you think that this block should be working from a weak
>   reference to self? I'm struggling to imagine it's important, since we
>   log a lot of stuff, all the time and I don't believe we've ever seen
>   this crash before.

https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon/issues/2206

OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.1 (19B88)

I suppose it to be an inner bug of *NSTableView*. If you have any ideas, please, let me know.

Comment: Apparently you are over retaining some object in your table view. Can you post some code how you are implementing it? Without that it is impossible to help you.

Comment: I've added some details and similar problems in other projects(there is some code). If you have any idea what could cause the problem please let us know. Thanks for attention.

Comment: `objc_loadWeak` is called on a weak reference to the table view. Please tell us about the table view, how is it used and implemented? Did you try the static analyzer and diagnostics tools of Xcode?

Comment: Are you using a custom NSView to populate the NSTableView? Moreover, the crashes seem to take place when these NSViews are being deallocated and the crash happens when NSTableView wants to refer to them after being released. Can you check if that happens when user closes the app after populating the table with such views? Moreover, what kind of model are you using to store the data you are using to populate the table?

Comment: @Willeke , thanks a lot for the simple and wise idea to check NSTableView's retainCount. Somewhy I tried to find a potential problem in cells and rows. I added some code and link to Github where you can find the whole test project. Please, let me know if you have any more ideas.

Comment: @jvarela thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: `NSTableRowData` retains and autoreleases the table view twice for each row when it is searching for group rows. Automatic row height has the same issue. On macOS 10.13 the retain count goes up to 67.000.000+. On macOS 10.15 the max retain count of `NSResponder` is 0x1FFFFFF = 33.554.431. Is the number of rows over 15.000.000?

Comment: @Willeke Do you know where I can read about it? Something like https://opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-417.18/kwq/KWQListBox.mm.auto.html but about NSTableView? Or some documentation... Or you got this information experimentally. My tests showed that NSTableView is retained only once for one row.(not 100% sure)

Comment: I just watched what happened. `outlineView:isGroupItem` is called from `-[NSTableRowData ensureGroupRowIndexes]`. After `-[NSTableRowData ensureGroupRowIndexes]` the retain count of the outline view is 67120009.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider it to be the *NSTableView* inner bug.

In my case commenting only the following method fixes the issue.

```
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isGroupItem:(id)item {
    return item == nil;
}
```

So, I made 2 objects for *NSTableViewDelegate* with *outlineView:isGroupItem:* method and without it. All the other calls I just proxied to the "previous" delegate.

```
- (void)updateInterfaceOfOutlineView {
    NSOutlineView *outlineView = self.outlineView;
    for (NSUInteger rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < outlineView.numberOfRows; rowIndex++) {
        @autoreleasepool {//Adding this autoreleasepool also increased the amount of possible rows in table.
            NSView *itemView = [outlineView viewAtColumn:0 row:rowIndex makeIfNecessary:NO];
            if(itemView && [itemView respondsToSelector:@selector(updateInterface)]) {
                [(id<SelectedItemView>)itemView updateInterface];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The legacy code... Don't be extremely critical about it.