# NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey freezes

Tags: objective-c, foundation

I am using NSUserDefaults to store NSNumber value.

```
- (void)saveValue {
    if(_key != nil) {
        if(_value != nil) {
            NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_value forKey:_key];
            NSTimeInterval t = -date.timeIntervalSinceNow;
            NSLog(@"%s - %lf", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, t);
        } else {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:_key];
        }
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}
```

(NSLog was added for test purposes, to show how long the operation takes)

But sometimes it takes seconds:

```
2019-12-16 16:10:37.450025+0200 MyProduct[23565:262671] -[CachedDefaultsValue saveValue] - 0.017004
2019-12-16 16:10:48.108883+0200 MyProduct[23565:262671] -[CachedDefaultsValue saveValue] - 6.022574
2019-12-16 16:10:57.670287+0200 MyProduct[23565:262671] -[CachedDefaultsValue saveValue] - 0.000176
2019-12-16 16:11:04.381613+0200 MyProduct[23565:262671] -[CachedDefaultsValue saveValue] - 0.000142
2019-12-16 16:11:20.034960+0200 MyProduct[23565:262671] -[CachedDefaultsValue saveValue] - 3.018475
2019-12-16 16:11:25.661984+0200 MyProduct[23565:262671] -[CachedDefaultsValue saveValue] - 0.000185
2019-12-16 16:11:40.863433+0200 MyProduct[23565:262671] -[CachedDefaultsValue saveValue] - 3.017213
```

I was surprised that [-[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1414067-setobject?language=objc) takes so long. Up to **6 seconds** as you can see in the log above.

I followed the suggestion and removed all the [-[NSUserDefaults synchronize]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1414005-synchronize?language=objc) methods.

> synchronize Waits for any pending asynchronous updates to the defaults
>   database and returns; this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be
>   used.

```
2019-12-16 16:36:16.827763+0200 MyProduct[30538:298345] -[CachedDefaultsValue saveValue] - 0.018135
2019-12-16 16:36:27.496848+0200 MyProduct[30538:298345] -[CachedDefaultsValue saveValue] - 3.017637
2019-12-16 16:36:37.759195+0200 MyProduct[30538:298345] -[CachedDefaultsValue saveValue] - 1.014380
2019-12-16 16:36:47.239685+0200 MyProduct[30538:298345] -[CachedDefaultsValue saveValue] - 0.000139
2019-12-16 16:36:52.877213+0200 MyProduct[30538:298345] -[CachedDefaultsValue saveValue] - 0.000140
2019-12-16 16:37:03.623115+0200 MyProduct[30538:298345] -[CachedDefaultsValue saveValue] - 0.000298
2019-12-16 16:37:19.192752+0200 MyProduct[30538:298345] -[CachedDefaultsValue saveValue] - 4.013809
```

But in any way, I got **3 and 4 seconds freezes**.

- macOS: 10.14.5 (18F132)
- XCode Version 11.2.1 (11B500)

Does anyone have any idea how the freeze can be solved?
Or some ways to research the issue...

Comment: I'd say most heavy operation here is NSLog, and as recommended by Apple you should not call `synchronize` explicitly... it will be done automatically when needed.

Comment: @Asperi , thanks for the suggestions. 1. *NSLog* was added for test purposes(to figure out how long the saving takes), Also *NSLog* related code was modified a bit. 2. I did remove all *synchronize* methods used in my project. and updated freezes test. Unfortunately, the issue is not solved. I'll be thankful for any following suggestions.

Comment: You only show **one** `NSLog()` statement, but you are showing **seven** output lines... so I assume you are calling `saveValue` seven times. What are you doing in-between the calls to `saveValue`?

Comment: @DonMag it is hard to say what part of code causes freeze. There is a lot of stuff going on. I do switch several screens. Select a file in a table. And remove it. At the moment I try both: **1.** Find the "buggy line" in the big project(where I faced the issue) and **2.** reproduce the freeze in "Hello World" project.

Comment: @DonMag , my code just shows how much time setObject:forKey: method takes in my case. Just to show at least some evidence.

Comment: @DonMag , I hope, I'll manage to reproduce the issue in a simple project as I did here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59141491/nsresponder-tryretain-crash

Comment: @ZevsVU - yep, a [mcve] would help. By the way - is this on iOS or MacOS?

Comment: @DonMag
macOS: 10.14.5 (18F132),
XCode Version 11.2.1 (11B500).